# How can I make the whole page scrollable?

Tags: widget, flutter, flutter-layout

Instead of just scrollable FirebaseAnimatedList, I want to make the whole page scrollable i.e. the parent Column widget that includes the form and the FirebaseAnimatedList.

I'm stuck at this since long and tried various different widget but couldn't make it.
Please Help.

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(
        flex: 0,
        child: Center(
          child: Form(
            key: formkey,
            child: Flex(
              direction: Axis.vertical,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.subject),
                  title: TextFormField(
                    initialValue: "",
                    onSaved: (val) => board.subject = val,
                    validator: (val) => val == "" ? val : null,
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.message),
                  title: TextFormField(
                    initialValue: "",
                    onSaved: (val) => board.body = val,
                    validator: (val) => val == "" ? val : null,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: FlatButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "POST",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    onPressed: () {
                      handleSubmit();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
          query: databaseReference,
          itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot snapshot,
              Animation<double> animation, int index) {
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
                title: Text(boardMessages[index].subject),
                subtitle: Text(boardMessages[index].body),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

With SingleChildScrollView I'm able to scroll the page by holding form widget but it doesn't scroll by holding the FirebaseAnimatedList widget.

```
LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: new BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
          ),
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                height: 180.0,
                child: Center(
                    child: Form(
                      key: formkey,
                      child: Flex(
                        direction: Axis.vertical,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.subject),
                            title: TextFormField(
                              initialValue: "",
                              onSaved: (val) => board.subject = val,
                              validator: (val) => val == "" ? val : null,
                            ),
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.message),
                            title: TextFormField(
                              initialValue: "",
                              onSaved: (val) => board.body = val,
                              validator: (val) => val == "" ? val : null,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: FlatButton(
                              child: Text(
                                "POST",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              color: Colors.blueGrey,
                              onPressed: () {
                                handleSubmit();
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ),
              new Container(
                height: 2000.0,
                child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
                    query: databaseReference,
                    itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                        Animation<double> animation, int index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                          ),
                          title: Text(boardMessages[index].subject),
                          subtitle: Text(boardMessages[index].body),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  )
```

And what should be the height of Container containing the FirebaseAnimatedList?

Comment: SinglePageScrollView may be what you want. Or ListView

Comment: Agreed with @RémiRousselet, these are the possible 2 easy way to go for.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thanks for the quick response. With SingleChildScrollView I'm able to scroll the page by holding form widget but it doesn't scroll by holding the FirebaseAnimatedList widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Column() to ListView() as so
also try adding a listview on the outside of your FirebaseAnimatedList 
Container()

```
    ListView(
children: <Widget>[
  Flexible(
    flex: 0,
    child: Center(
      child: Form(
        key: formkey,
        child: Flex(
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.subject),
              title: TextFormField(
                initialValue: "",
                onSaved: (val) => board.subject = val,
                validator: (val) => val == "" ? val : null,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.message),
              title: TextFormField(
                initialValue: "",
                onSaved: (val) => board.body = val,
                validator: (val) => val == "" ? val : null,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  "POST",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                onPressed: () {
                  handleSubmit();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  Flexible(
    child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
      query: databaseReference,
      itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot snapshot,
          Animation<double> animation, int index) {
        return Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
            title: Text(boardMessages[index].subject),
            subtitle: Text(boardMessages[index].body),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the whole page to be **scrollable** which means it need to wrap the content inside `ScollView(ListView)`.

Which will make having `scrollView(FirebaseAnimatedList)` **inside** an another `ScrollView(ListView)`. Flutter cannot handle this by its own. We have to give some more information to it.

**Options:**

1. Provide the height for the inner scrollView.

   ```
   Container(
      height: 500.0, //some constant value
      child: FirebaseAnimatedList(...))
   ```

   It doesn't scroll by holding the `FirebaseAnimatedList` widget.
2. Make the `innerScollView` not scrollable.

   ```
   FirebaseAnimatedList(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: ...)
   ```

It **does scroll by holding** the `FirebaseAnimatedList` widget. **Note:** But it will load all the elements in the list(say you have 200 items, it will load all 200 items whether the item is visible or not).

Comment: this worked but the height of each item of FirebaseAnimatedList is not fixed.
If it was fixed I would have given height to the container this way :
`Container(
   height: boardMessages.length * Some_constant_value , 
   child: FirebaseAnimatedList(...))`
but it's not fixed.

Comment: If you want the `boardMessages.length * some_constant_value`, the option two will do that.

Comment: To make this work I had to combine both the options. this is how my code looks like: `Container(
                    height: boardMessages.length * 80.0,
                    child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      query: databaseReference,
                      itemBuilder:`

Comment: If your not wrapping `FirebaseAnimatedList` inside `Container` what is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add FirebaseAnimatedList and other items in ListView, like below:

```
ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: <Widget>[
         _buildCard(),
         FirebaseAnimatedList(...),
]);
```

You should disable FirebaseAnimatedList scroll too

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
         physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
         shrinkWrap: true, ...)
```